# Some unused space at top of each page. What is it for?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

[image]

This is how my app looks like. Every page I open has some blank space at top. What is it and how can I use it on Windows UWP or how can I disable it?

Platform: Windows 10 UWP, Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 0):

You can find out it by your self. If you open top menu and choose this tool:
[image]

So you can investigate your layout by clicking on necessary element. Then in Live Visual tree you can see name of element, where it been declared, other visual props.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> What is it and how can I use it on Windows UWP or how can I disable it?

This should be **NavigationBar**, we can disable it using [`NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar/p/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/System.Boolean/) method.

For example:

```
public ViewA()
{
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
}
```

**Reference:** [Xamarin Forms Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099049/xamarin-forms-action-bar)